# When deploying Android app on device, it duplicates

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-launcher, android-debug

I have created and included a launcher activity on my android app , I have deleted the activity's .java and .xml file. But now when i deploy the app on a device, im getting duplicates of the app on the device.

How does one go about removing it?

Comment: It means there are two same project name with different packagename.You have to uninstall the previous apk file on the device.

Comment: Or you have two activities in your manifest set up with `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` elements. Or, you only have one, but it is a different activity than before, and the home screen is caching the old one. Try rebooting the device to clear up the latter problem.

Comment: can you show you menifest please.

Comment: Different package names or different launcher activities could be the problem. Follow @Soham's advice.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks man... that was the problem.... i got it fixed!